# Offline package installation

Tags: software-installation

I want to install some packages without internet connection.

Please suggest the ways to copy already installed packages on "System1" to "System2" (System2 without internet connection).

Answer (score -1):

**Copying files**

Take a look at `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You could copy them to System2 using a USB disk or via ssh (if it has local network access).
This might not work if your don't repeat this each time you update System1, because you might miss dependencies which were installed in  the meantime. So: Not recommended.

**Local network mirror**

Also, you could setup a [local network apt mirror](https://apt-mirror.github.io/), which is possibly the best solution.

**Create a CD or USB-Disk**

For this, try [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/), [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/) or [AptMedium](https://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium). All do more or less the same - choose your flavour.

Comment: A network mirror will work only if it System2 is networked, which I think is not the case. APTonCD is obsolete(last development activity for the project was in the year 2007). For apt-medium there has been no development since 2009, other than a spelling correction.

Comment: @daltonfury42 Objection. He says, System2 is without internet connection. That's not the same as "without network connection". Please read the question more carefully.

Even though the mentioned projects are obsolete, it doesn't mean they won't work. In fact, they do just fine.

Comment: Have you tested them yourselves?

Comment: Some of them, about 1.5 years ago. Sadly I don't remember which one.
I do remember using http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Lokale_Paketquellen/apt-cacher and https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ubumirror, and there are also https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu-Mirror and  https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/apt-mirror.
German ubuntu community has usefull articles, if you can read german.

Comment: Giving it another thought, apt-cacher might be the best solution for small environments.